# Why does accessing an object's __dict__ cause memory leaks?

Tags: python, class, memory-management

I have the following Python class.

```py
from functools import lru_cache

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bar = lru_cache()(self._bar)
    
    def _bar(self):
        return 'bar'
    
    def __del__(self):
        print(f'deleting Foo instance {self}')
```

Calling it like this works as I expected, and the `foo` object is removed.

```py
foo = Foo()
foo  # note id
# <__main__.Foo object at 0x104f48a70>
weak_foo = weakref.ref(foo)
foo.bar()
# 'bar'
del foo
gc.collect()
# deleting Foo instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x104f48a70>
# 8
assert weak_foo() is None
```

However, if I access the `__dict__`, the object is not deleted with the garbage collector.

```py
foo_dict = Foo()
foo_dict  # note id in case you run multiple times
# <__main__.Foo object at 0x1050dfb30>
weak_foo_dict = weakref.ref(foo_dict)
foo_dict.bar()
# 'bar'
foo_dict.__dict__
# {'bar': <functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x104e90bf0>}
del foo_dict
gc.collect()
# 0
assert weak_foo_dict() is None
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# AssertionError
```

I understand that the cache holds a reference to the `foo` object via the `self` parameter which creates an issue with decorating instance methods with `lru_cache` (where the class holds a reference to the object through the cache). But I am thoroughly confused why accessing `__dict__` affects when it's removed in this case? Is construction of the dictionary delayed until it's accessed? Any pointers to helpful documentation would be appreciated.

Edit: Updated to try to clarify question. I noticed that if you run the garbage collector twice it does clean up the object regardless of whether the `__dict__` is accessed. Not that familiar with the gc so maybe that makes sense.
Using version 3.12.

Comment: But you get the name error in only one of those code blocks because only one of those code blocks tried to use the name (after it was removed from the namespace). The weakref is more interesting but you could have done more to demonstrate what you're asking about there.

Comment: Running your second code snippet works for me and shows `deleting Foo instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x10483fed0>` using Py3.11.4

Comment: I see the weakref alive after del foo and dead after gc.collect(), regardless of whether I look at dict. Looking at dict had no effect in your original code or after I added the weakref checks. Python 3.10.4 on windows

Comment: What happens if after doing `foo.__dict__` and before `del foo`, you do some inconsequential other operation like `print('hi')`? For me in a REPL, this changes the behaviour such that the "deleting Foo instance" is shown. I wonder if something is going on related to the fact that the REPL has a reference to the return value of the last thing executed (in order for it to be available as `_`).

Comment: @MauriceMeyer can you check the id of the removed instance and confirm it's the current object?